# How do I fix a Mass assignment security error from devise in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am using Devise in my Rails app for authentication.  When I attempt to sign up as a user, I get an error saying: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email, password, password_confirmation.  I didn't receive this error until I added a new column to my Users table named 'owner'.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable   
    attr_accessible :owner, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :as => :admin    
end
```

Migration to add user:

```
class AddOwnerToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :owner, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

Before I had added :owner, I dont' remember having this issue.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: I see problem in `User` model. is that same in our source file?

Comment: @HungryCoder I forgot to include a line, it's been added now.  Do you still see an problem in User.rb?

Comment: Hmm, I am still getting the error (I just accidentally deleted that line when I made the post the first time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that sure about the usages of `:as` in the `attr_accessible`. I've never used that.  So far I've understood, you have to specify this when you updating mass attributes like:

```
User.new(params[:user], :as => :admin)
```

or,

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
```